# Angular: refactoring controllers turn $routeParams to undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm splitting my angular code in different modules and I'm facing an issue. I suppose I don't understand the internals of services injection.

going from controllers defined as global functions

```
angular.module('foo', []);
function fooCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
```

to a declarative form in order to have them as part of a module

```
angular.module('foo',[]).
controller(['fooCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
```

in the end I lose the $routeParams service (undefined). Do I need to inject explicitly my $routeParams to the module? How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears like you are not calling your `controller()` correctly.

```
angular.module('foo',[]).
controller("fooCtrl", <-- controller name
    ['$scope', '$routeParams', <-- list of dependencies
    function($scope, $routeParams) { <--actual controller function
       alert($routeParams);
}]);
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/BQYN2/)**

If you don't plan on doing minification you can also do the following:

```
angular.module('foo',[]).controller("fooCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams) {   
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, will accept when I can (5 minutes delay). Is this done this way so I can obfuscate the code later on?

Comment: That is correct, so Angular knows that `$scope` is the first parameter in  the function even when it gets minified to `a`